# Como ordenar a listagem de uma consulta utilizando curl_setopt_array?

Tags: php

Estou populando um *Dropdown*, sendo que preciso ordernar pelo *Label*.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "url...,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(....

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$bairro = json_decode($response, true);

foreach ($bairro as $response) {
    $value = $response["CodBairro"];
    $label = $response["DescBairro"];
    
    $items[] = $value . '|' . $label;
}

$items = implode("\n", $items);
return $items;
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando o [`array_sort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sort.php) do *php*, onde é possível explicitar qual o campo de ordenação:

```
//array_sort(array_a_ser_ordenado, campo_de_ordenacao, ordem_escolhida)
foreach (array_sort($bairro, 'DescBairro', SORT_ASC) as $response) {
    $value = $response["CodBairro"];
    $label = $response["DescBairro"];

    $items[] = $value.'|'.$label;
}
```

obs: se preferir pode fazer isso já no array ordenado (`$items`), não acredito que tenha qualquer diferença de performance.

```
$items = array_sort($items, $label, SORT_ASC);
```